# Steam cannot "explicitly" access files from ANY partition on Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, permissions, mount, games, steam

there used to be an issue where I'd have to unmount and remount a drive multiple times in addition to rebooting my Ubuntu system numerous times too, just to have a chance of fixing Steam not being able to see my second games directory.

However, until now, Steam is no longer able to read anymore when I try to make it to (This will hopefully make sense later in the post) than what it knows.
(With the exception of being able to install games?)

For example, if I launch Steam through the Terminal, and try to add a new game directory, all it shows me is a blank screen like [this, showing a completely empty panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPOtL.png)

This was weird, as before it was showing me the folders completely fine but now somehow it cant see anything? Then when I check the terminal for any weird lines I find this:

```
Couldn't write /snap/core/15419/.steam_exec_test.sh: Read-only file system
Couldn't write /snap/bombsquad/9/.steam_exec_test.sh: Read-only file system
Couldn't write /snap/core/15511/.steam_exec_test.sh: Read-only file system
Couldn't write /snap/core20/1974/.steam_exec_test.sh: Read-only file system
Couldn't write /snap/core22/858/.steam_exec_test.sh: Read-only file system
Couldn't write /snap/core18/2785/.steam_exec_test.sh: Read-only file system
Couldn't write /snap/core22/817/.steam_exec_test.sh: Read-only file system
Couldn't write /snap/tmnationsforever/51/.steam_exec_test.sh: Read-only file system
Couldn't write /snap/wine-platform-runtime/349/.steam_exec_test.sh: Read-only file system
Couldn't write /snap/tree/18/.steam_exec_test.sh: Read-only file system
Couldn't write /snap/wine-platform-runtime/348/.steam_exec_test.sh: Read-only file system
Couldn't write /snap/wine-platform-3-stable/14/.steam_exec_test.sh: Read-only file system`
```

**Before saying that I should uninstall the snap version of Steam, I didn't install the snap version of steam, but rather the .deb from their website.**

Turns out every Steam version whether from their website or from snap checks for this either way

Upon trying to change the screenshots folder, Surprisingly [it DOES show folders,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8f9Z.png) but immediately crashes once you have selected a folder, but it doesn't crash when you create a folder? The crash makes a crashdump file that contains some type of memory dump that is gibberish (atleast to me, however if you want to take a look I'd post this later)

I checked my mount permissions and tags in the Disks program within Ubuntu to check if there is anything weird, but thats as far as I've gotten in terms of trying to fix this safely, Why isn't Steam able to choose directories?

Comment: Stop thrashing! Diagnose first, then fixPlease read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour]..

Comment: Everything in `/snap/` is read-only. That is expected behavior.

Comment: but why does it not read anything and crash whenever i try to select a directory? and upon trying to search for a game directory it just ends up not showing anything in the game directory selection panel